# Is it possible to include antiforgerytoken in XMLHttpRequest header?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I am using a library called [Slim](http://slimimagecropper.com/), to upload images to my asp.net MVC project.

The JQuery library is using XMLHttpRequest to send requests to the server, I have gone through all the manual and there is nothing about how to include anti forgery token to the server.

So I manually added this line before the send:

```
data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
```

Even though the token is included in the data, the Asp.net MVC filter: *ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute* is not recognizing it, as it is expecting the token to be in the *header*. here is the validation code on the server:

```
AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null,
                             httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
```

and here is the library's send function with the extra line that I have added at the buttom to include the token. How can include the token in the header?

```
var send = function send(url, data, requestDecorator, progress, success, err) {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// if progress callback defined handle progress events
if (progress) {
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        progress(e.loaded, e.total);
    });
}

// open the request
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

// if request decorator defined pass XMLHttpRequest instance to decorator
if (requestDecorator) {
    requestDecorator(xhr);
}

// handle state changes
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {

        var text = xhr.responseText;

        // if no data returned from server assume success
        if (!text.length) {
            success();
            return;
        }

        // catch possible PHP content length problem
        if (text.indexOf('Content-Length') !== -1) {
            err('file-too-big');
            return;
        }

        // if data returned it should be in suggested JSON format
        var obj = void 0;
        try {
            obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        } catch (e) {}

        // if is failure response
        if ((typeof obj === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(obj)) === 'object' && obj.status === 'failure') {
            err(obj.message);
            return;
        }

        success(obj || text);
    } else if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

        var _obj = void 0;
        try {
            _obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        } catch (e) {}

        // if is clean failure response
        if ((typeof _obj === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(_obj)) === 'object' && _obj.status === 'failure') {
            err(_obj.message);
            return;
        }

        err('fail');
    }
};

// I have added this line to library to include anti forgery token
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

// do request
xhr.send(data);
```

};
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the antiforgerytoken in the header like this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
```

see [XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) for more information about XMLHttpRequest:

To verify the AntiforgeryToken passed in the header, in your controller, you need to create your own filter, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MySlimAction()
{
    /* your Save controller logic goes here */
}
```

Add this filter definition as a new class to your Filters folder:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null,
                             httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
    }
}
```

In case of your specific library, [Slim Image Cropper](http://slimimagecropper.com), you can use *willRequest* call back while initializing Slim:

```
var cropper = $('#my-cropper-selector').slim({
  willRequest: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
  },
  ratio: 'free',
  push: true,
  service: '/MyController/MySlimAction'
  /* other options go here */
});
```

Comment: For others: the `__RequestVerificationToken` must be present as both formdata and in the headers

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is still struggling on this, here is a solution:

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());

without the '__', so this won't work:

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());

And in Backend you can use the already known built in [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] Attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteTenantRole()
```

Works as expected.
No need to create your own Filter Attribute